# Second monitor not detected Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

So, with my old laptop I didn't have any problem using a second monitor. But with this one, it doesn't work. The second monitor using a HDMI connection displays "No signal"...

```
inxi -Fx
System:    Host: peter-ROG-Strix-G531GU-G531GU Kernel: 5.3.0-45-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.5.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4)
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ROG Strix G531GU_G531GU v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G531GU v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: G531GU.306 date: 09/24/2019
Battery    BAT0: charge: 61.9 Wh 100.0% condition: 61.9/66.0 Wh (94%)
           model: ASUSTeK ASUS status: Not charging
CPU:       6 core Intel Core i7-9750H (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: Skylake rev.10 cache: 12288 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 31199
           clock speeds: max: 4500 MHz 1: 800 MHz 2: 811 MHz 3: 815 MHz
           4: 800 MHz 5: 800 MHz 6: 819 MHz 7: 800 MHz 8: 817 MHz 9: 811 MHz
           10: 800 MHz 11: 814 MHz 12: 813 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 3e9b bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 2191 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 ) driver: i915
           Resolution: 1920x1080@120.04hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Card-2 NVIDIA Device 1aeb driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.3.0-45-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
           driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 00:14.3
           IF: wlo1 state: down mac: 0c:dd:24:40:b2:7b
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 port: 3000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: eno2 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: 04:d4:c4:e1:9c:7d
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 516.1GB (2.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: Micron_2200V_MTFDHBA512TCK size: 512.1GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sda model: UDisk size: 4.0GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 240G used: 8.2G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 51.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 327 Uptime: 9 min Memory: 1600.0/15861.4MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.5.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Result of "xrandr"

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    120.04*+  48.01
```

My ubuntu-drivers devices:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002191sv00001043sd000010FFbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d0000A370sv00008086sd00000034bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

And when I enter nvidia-settings...

```
nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** Message: 19:08:27.492: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 19:08:27.492: PRIME: is it supported? yes

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug


(nvidia-settings:5498): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:08:31.975: gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0' failed

(nvidia-settings:5498): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:08:31.975: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 12 and height -12

(nvidia-settings:5498): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:08:31.975: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar

(nvidia-settings:5498): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:08:31.975: gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0' failed

(nvidia-settings:5498): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:08:31.975: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 12 and height -12

(nvidia-settings:5498): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 19:08:31.975: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

So do you know how to fix it? Cause I tryed several solutions like install Ubuntu 20.04... But nothing happend...

**Edit:**

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia 
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64                   430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-430                       430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-435                       435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:amd64                430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:i386                 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64                435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:amd64                 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:i386                  430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:amd64                 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:i386                  430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64                   430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386                    430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:amd64                     430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:i386                      430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64                   430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386                    430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-430                   430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-435                   435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-430                            430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-435                            435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-430                          430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-430                   430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-435                   435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-430                   430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                                          all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            390.77-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-430                           430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430              430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```